# How to pass a parameter to an executable which is then used as the handle reference in PostMessage?

Tags: c#

Our customer is providing us with a handle window value that they send to a SQL table. This needs to be passed to a `PostMessage()` call in an exe. Any ideas how this can be done? I can't see a way of converting the input parameter into the correct data type for the first parameter in `PostMessage` e.g.

```
bool PMSuccess = PostMessage(sWindowName, sWindowMessage, 0, 0);
```

I need to pass the parameter in the command line to `sWindowName`?

Comment: Converting seems to be easy... so what do you *have* problems with? Does it compile? Does it run? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the window handle with `FindWindow` from Win32 API.

```
HWND FindWindow( LPCTSTR lpClassName, LPCTSTR lpWindowName );
```

lpClassName can be NULL.